# Nested Query equivalent to inner join

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join, subquery

I'm trying to better understand nested queries, and I was wondering what would get me the same result as this:

```
SELECT PLAYERS.PLAYER_TAG, PLAYERS.POSITION, PLAYERS.TOTAL_KILLS, TEAMS.TEAM_NAMES, TEAMS.GAMES_PLAYED, TEAMS.WINS
FROM PLAYERS
INNER JOIN TEAMS ON TEAMS.TEAM_NAMES = PLAYERS.TEAM
ORDER BY TEAM_NAMES ASC;
```

but using a nested query instead. Thanks for your help

Comment: Where do you expect the nested query to be used in your example?

Answer (score 0):

This is not that kind of query when you need any nested ones (sub-queries) due to lack of any predicates (WHERE clause).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You would not use this and would just use the `INNER JOIN` query.

However, if a player will only ever be on one team then this query:

```sql
SELECT PLAYER_TAG,
       POSITION, 
       TOTAL_KILLS,
       ( SELECT TEAM_NAMES
         FROM   teams
         WHERE  TEAMS.TEAM_NAMES = PLAYERS.TEAM ) AS teams_names,
       ( SELECT GAMES_PLAYED
         FROM   teams
         WHERE  TEAMS.TEAM_NAMES = PLAYERS.TEAM ) AS games_played,
       ( SELECT WINS
         FROM   teams
         WHERE  TEAMS.TEAM_NAMES = PLAYERS.TEAM ) AS wins
FROM   PLAYERS
ORDER BY TEAM_NAMES ASC;
```

*(If a player can be on multiple teams then the above query will raise an exception as the nested sub-queries return more than a single row.)*

Would be the (inefficient) equivalent of:

```sql
SELECT PLAYERS.PLAYER_TAG,
       PLAYERS.POSITION,
       PLAYERS.TOTAL_KILLS,
       TEAMS.TEAM_NAMES,
       TEAMS.GAMES_PLAYED,
       TEAMS.WINS
FROM   PLAYERS
       LEFT OUTER JOIN TEAMS
       ON TEAMS.TEAM_NAMES = PLAYERS.TEAM
ORDER BY TEAM_NAMES ASC;
```

*(Using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` rather than an `INNER JOIN`.)*

If you wanted an `INNER JOIN` then you can add an `EXISTS` filter to the outer query's `WHERE` clause.